# How can I get access to the script of a Python package in Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, rasa-nlu

I am using Ubuntu for a Python project and want to get access to the script of rasa_nlu.evaluate so that I can better understand it and call the function within it with the appropriate arguments.

I am using the 0.11.5 versio of rasa_nlu. I tried to go in the usr/bin/ directory but cannot seem to be able to go any further. When I try `cd /python` on the Ubuntu shell, I get "No such file or directory".

Alternatively, can I find the code on GitHub? (it seems that I can only find the code of the 12.0 version of rasa...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

source for rasa_nlu is hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu

you can clone the repo with Git, or view the `evaluate.py` source right from GitHub in your browser

- current master branch: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/evaluate.py
- 11.5 version: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/0.11.5/rasa_nlu/evaluate.py

Comment: Dear Corey,

Thank you very much for your answer. However, this seems to be the code for version 12.0 while I am looking for the code of the script used in version 11.5...